# Cannot Select drawn features on multiple layers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using Openlayers 2.12 with Firefox 18.0.

I'm just adding an EditingToolbar to this example :

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html

So basically I change this :

```
map.addLayers([wmsLayer, vectors1, vectors2]);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature
(
    [vectors1, vectors2],
    {
        clickout: true, toggle: false,
        multiple: false, hover: false,
    }
);

map.addControl(selectControl);
selectControl.activate();
```

by adding one line :

```
map.addLayers([wmsLayer, vectors1, vectors2]);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(vectors2));
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature
(
    [vectors1, vectors2],
    {
        clickout: true, toggle: false,
        multiple: false, hover: false,
    }
);

map.addControl(selectControl);
selectControl.activate();
```

And now I can't select features (that I draw) correctly on any layers, got any leads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have mentioned is derived from dragging handler activation when you adding Editing Toolbar to map.

`map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(vectors2));`

you have two ways to get rid of this problem.

first way:

add a new tool to activating and toggling select control.

second way:

try to set `false` to drag prototype.

```
OpenLayers.Handler.Drag.prototype.stopDown = false;
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Second way is working like a charm, thank you very very much. I didn't get the explanation about the dragging handler and I'm a bit confused about the first way.

Comment: you are welcome. the first way is adding a new tool as drag handler tool or adding new point tool. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have panel area for display controls, you can set 'allowDepress' attribute to deactivate by clicking the icon that represents them.